# React Native app crashed after fetching data

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have weird issue. I have working react native application on iOS, but on android it crashes without an error after fetching data. It started to happen when I ejected expo app, before that it worked. If I remove network request application works

What can be the problem?

Comment: You first need to find some logs in order to have an helpful answer. If you use any tool like Flipper, you can easily find the app crash log or the react-native app logs. After ejecting expo, did you install any new package? Or what was the reason you ejected it?

Comment: @MikaAndrianarijaona Yes, I've installed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tap-payments/gosell-sdk-react-native. I ejected app to use this package, because it doesn't work with expo environment, but iOS application works great

Comment: Does you Android app have all the requirements as described in the installation section?

Comment: @MikaAndrianarijaona Yes, it has everything. The problem goes not from plugin, but after fetch request ends. Flipper also doesn't show an error log

Comment: If I remove network request application works

Comment: @MikaAndrianarijaona thanks for replying me, I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

In `app/build.gradle` need to change line

from `implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2"` to

```
api(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.7.2"))
api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
```